# How to fix bad URI(is not URI?) in ruby on rails :URI::InvalidURIError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, weather-api

I am unable to pass variables as parameters to this api: wounderground.

I want to take inputs as city and state using input boxes and pass them as variables to the URI so that users can get their weather forecast.  However I am unable to pass variables as parameters to the api and am getting bad URI(is not URI?) or URI::InvalidURIError.  Can somebody please tell me how to fix it and tell me why I'm getting this error. if you need more information please let me know.  Thanks!

**model: weathers.rb**
    class Weathers

```
attr_accessor :temperature, :city, :state, :icon, :weekday_name, 
:chance_of_rain, :chance_of_snow, :uvi, :tomorrow, :tomorrow_condition, 
:tomorrow_icon, :day_one, `enter code here`:day_one_condition, 
:day_one_high, :day_one_low, :day_two, :day_two_condition, 
:day_two_high, :day_two_low

def initialize(city, state)
@city = city
@state = state

week_weather_hash = fetch_week_forecast(city, state)
week_forecast(week_weather_hash)
end

def fetch_week_forecast(city, state)

HTTParty.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/apikey/forecast10day/q/#
{city}/#{state}.json")
end

def week_forecast(week_weather_hash)
weekly_forecast_response = 
week_weather_hash.parsed_response['response']['forecast']
self.day_one = weekly_forecast_response['txt_forecast']['forecastdays']
['forecastday'][0]['title']
self.day_one_condition = weekly_forecast_response['txt_forecast']
['forecastdays']`enter code here`['forecastday'][0]['fcttext']

self.day_one_high = weekly_forecast_response['simpleforecast']
['forecastdays']['forecastday'][0]['high']['fahrenheit']
self.day_one_low = weekly_forecast_response['simpleforecast']
['forecastdays']['forecastday'][0]['low']['fahrenheit']

self.day_two = weekly_forecast_response['txt_forecast']['forecastdays']
['forecastday'][2]['title']
self.day_two_condition = weekly_forecast_response['txt_forecast']
['forecastdays']`enter code here`['forecastday'][2]['fcttext']

self.day_two_high = weekly_forecast_response['simpleforecast']
['forecastdays']`enter code here`['forecastday'][1]['high']
['fahrenheit']
self.day_two_low = weekly_forecast_response['simpleforecast']
['forecastdays']['forecastday'][1]['low']['fahrenheit']
```

**This is my controller:**
    class ForecastsController < ApplicationController
    def show
    @weather = Weathers.new(params[:city], params[:state])
    end
    end

**show.html.erb**
    
    Weekly forecast:
    
    
    <%=@weathers.day_one %> : <%= @weathers.day_one_condition %> 
    
    High/Low: <%=@weathers.day_one_high %>F : <%=@weathers.day_one_low %>F

```
<br>
<%=@weathers.day_two %> : <%= @weathers.day_two_condition %>
<br>
High/Low: <%=@weathers.day_two_high %>F : <%=@weathers.day_two_low 
%>F
```

**my index.html.erb and new form **

```
<%= form_tag("/forecast", method: "get", class: "form-inline") do %> 
<p class = "city-input">
<%= label_tag :City %>
<%= text_field_tag :city,  nil, class: "form-control", placeholder: 
"City Name" %>
</p>

<p class= "state-input">
<%= label_tag :State %>
<%= select_tag :state, options_for_select(us_states, "NY"), class: 
"form-control" %>
</p>

<p class= "submit">
<%= submit_tag 'Search', name: nil, class:"btn btn-primary" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

**Below is the the full stack trace of the error**

Started GET "/forecast?utf8=%E2%9C%93&city=new+york&state=NY" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-26 20:09:14 -0400
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY "schema_migrations"."version" ASC
Processing by ForecastsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "city"=>"new york", "state"=>"NY"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 10ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

URI::InvalidURIError (bad URI(is not URI?): http://api.wunderground.com/api/apikey/forecast10day/q/new york/NY.json):

app/models/weathers.rb:15:in `fetch_week_forecast'
app/models/weathers.rb:10:in`initialize'
app/controllers/forecasts_controller.rb:36:in `new'
app/controllers/forecasts_controller.rb:36:in`show'

**Continuation of error**
bad URI(is not URI?): http://api.wunderground.com/api/apikey/forecast10day/q/new york/NY.json

Extracted source (around line #15):
13
14
15
16
17
18

```
def fetch_week_forecast(city, state)
    HTTParty.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/apikey/forecast10day/q/#{city}/#{state}.json")
end

def week_forecast(week_weather_hash)
```

Comment: Please clean up your code by deleting `enter code here` and indenting properly.  I got you started with an edit, but there is still more to do.

Comment: I have removed the 'enter code here'

Comment: Post the full stack trace of your error.

Comment: Alright, I’m rushing home to post it.  Thank you!

Comment: I updated the question with the full stack trace of the error.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use HTTParty.get you pass the city and state that are "dynamic" values, as in this case city is "new york", the url is being created with a whitespace, and that's why you get the error:

> URI::InvalidURIError (bad URI(is not URI?):
>   http://api.wunderground.com/api/apikey/forecast10day/q/new
>   york/NY.json)

You could use `URI.encode(url)` and this way, the whitespace would be "converted" to `%20`, like:

```
http://api.wunderground.com/api/apikey/forecast10day/q/new%20york/NY.json
```

Which is a "valid" url to work with. So you can tweak a little bit your `fetch_week_forecast` method, like:

```
def fetch_week_forecast(city, state)
  HTTParty.get(URI.encode("http://api.wunderground.com/api/apikey/forecast10day/q/#{city}/#{state}.json"))
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sebastian!!! - the URI.encode converted the whitespace to....  Now, users can fetch weather data when they enter their city and state :)